# Listing Windows user accounts that are visible to user at login screen

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I would like to list Windows user accounts but ONLY those that are visible at login screen, one that is displayed after windows boots.

I googled and all I found boils down to this method:
http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-create-hidden-user-account-hide-user-account-from-welcome-screen-in-windows/

However, on my computer there are no registry keys that are mentioned in the above article - I don't want to create them, I want to check something that already exists.

I use the following query:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
{
     if (isInteresting(obj))
     {
         list.Add(obj.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString());
     }
}
```

With properties of objects that are returned by the above query I managed to filter some accounts (full list of those properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394507(v=vs.85).aspx#properties), but there is still some junk from the point of view of everyday user (like accounts used for updates by driver vendors).

Comment: then check if they exist too. obviously they arent set if they dont exist.

Comment: Check if what exists too? Sorry I don't get your answer.

Comment: Well, they don't exist on my computer (as I mentioned above) and I didn't delete them -> they don't exist on each computer. I am looking for a method which works on each computer that has Windows installed.

Comment: the keys obviously are not set if they don't exist.

Comment: Yes, that is true but I don't really see how this gets me closer to listing users visible on login screen. On my computer there are a few users, only one visible, and no keys mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That registry key isn't the only reason why an account might not be displayed on the logon screen.  Here are a few others:

- The account is disabled
- The account does not have interactive logon privilege (SeInteractiveLogonRight)
- The account is explicitly denied interactive logon privilege (SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight)

Usually SeInteractiveLogonRight is granted to the Guest user, plus members of the Administrators, Users, and Backup Operators groups.  Any account (other than Guest) that isn't a member of one of these groups will probably not be shown on the logon screen.  (I'm not sure what happens if SeInteractiveLogonRight has been removed from one of these groups, I wouldn't be surprised if the logon screen showed the accounts anyway.)

You can use [LsaEnumerateAccountRights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721790%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check whether an account has SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight applied, or [LsaEnumerateAccountsWithUserRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a list of affected accounts.  Usually individual accounts, rather than groups, are granted this right, so it is likely that the logon screen checks accounts in this way.